# C# ADO.NET SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

When I do something like

```
string connString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;";
string sql = @"select name, age from dbo.Student";

SqlDataReader reader;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd;

conn.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

While I'm running SQL Server named `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` on my local machine. How does the application know that I'm connecting to the local database since that's just a name not an address like IP address? And why doesn't it work when I try changing the Data Source to be something like "127.0.0.1" ?

I'm new to ASP.NET. Thanks for comments.

Comment: Read up on [instancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/178292/why-is-127-0-0-1-localhost-needed-in-hosts-file

Comment: You can just change `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` to `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`. You'll have to use the name of the instance in both cases though.

Comment: Try this: string connString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True";

Answer (score 0):

> How does the application know that I'm connecting to the local database since that's just a name not an address like IP address?

It works in the same way you'd access stackoverflow.com by typing stackoverflow.com into the address bar. It does a DNS look-up and resolves the IP address for you itself. You can type your IP address (and the instance name, see next point) yourself if you wish, it'll still work. `localhost` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`

> I and why doesn't it work when I try changing the Data Source to be something like "127.0.0.1" ?

Because you gave it just the IP, so it will have reached your machine successfully - but you've ommitted the SQL Server instance name. It should look like this instead:

> Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;

(Notice the 'SQLExpress')

There are a ton of articles about if you wish to get a better handle on DNS, which you should have at least a basic understanding of: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/dns-lookup

Answer (score 0):

on your c drive assuming that your windows is installed there 
go to and open this file in notepad
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

you will see in it

## 127.0.0.1       localhost

this maps the ip address 127.0.0.1 to local host